# can't find "buildkernel" target in FreeBSD source files

Tags: kernel, freebsd, make

I'm trying to compile a FreeBSD 9.3 Kernel. in the docs it states that the commands `make buildkernel` and `make installkernel` must be run, However I can't find these two targets anywhere in the make files, ("I haven't tried running them yet"), I have even `ack`ed them but could only find usages and not where they are defined..

Comment: Why not try `make -n buildkernel` and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

I tried as G-man suggested in the comments.The main Makefile will include the 'Makefile.inc1' and pass some parameters to it e.g: `TARGET_ARCH=i386`, that's where `buildkernel` is defined.